# How to ignore deletion of a file based on file name during a .bat script run?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have certain XML files inside a folder(folder name - Tasks), when I run my batch script all the files in the folder should be deleted, except the files which have the word "Project" in their file names. I have gone through the answers related to batch scripting questions, but couldn't find any command or regular expression which would help me do this. I am using the below command inside my batch script, but it is not working for me.

```
del Tasks\^*Project\*.xml
```

I am new to batch scripting, any help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: So you want to delete all your xml files into a folder named `Tasks` expect which have the word `Project` in their file names ?

Comment: I need to delete the xml files in the folder named Tasks , except the files which have the word Project in their file names.

Comment: `mkdir \xxtemp`, `move *Project*.xml \xxtemp`, `del *.xml`, `move \xxtemp\*.xml .`, `rmdir \xxtemp`

Comment: Also note https://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a try for this batch and change the path of your folder :

And if every thing is OK after testing ; you can remove `echo` before `Del` command in this line :

`( echo Del "%%a")`

```bat
@echo off
Set "Folder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Scripting\Stack\Tasks"
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /B "%Folder%\*.xml" ^|find /I /V "Project"') do ( echo Del "%%a")
pause
```

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `Dir /?`
- `find /?`
- `Del /?`

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific, the word "Project" in the file name can be anywhere, like - MyProject.xml, Project_1.xml, NewProject.xml, etc., I tried changing the command by adding asterisks before and after the word Project, like this - "`*Project*`" . It still didn't work for me.

Comment: @Carthic, `find` with `/I` and `/V` should deselect any of the returned files from `Dir` which contain the case insensitive string, `project`, anywhere within its full path, so, as long as `%Folder%` does not contain the string `Project`, you should be okay. Hackoo, I would suggest that you remove the `/S` option from your `Dir` command. The question specifically states, `XML files inside a folder(folder name - Tasks)`. Currently your code could delete all files within subdirectrories of `Tasks`,, which may not be wanted, and was not requested,

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me Hackoo. My apologies, earlier I had set incorrect Directory path, hence it didn't execute the way I expected.

Comment: @Compo I edited the code refer to your comment !  Removed `/S` Thank you for your remark !

Comment: @Hackoo, you could also remove the not required `CD` line, or preferably omit `%Folder%\ ` from your `Dir` command. It may also be prudent, now you're not working with recursive paths with known first characters to include a `EOL` option too. _(`For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A-D "*.xml" ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I /V "project"') Do Echo Del /A /F "%%G"`)_

Answer (score 0):

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "skip=1 eol=; tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /b \Tasks*.xml') do (

@echo %%i |find "Project"

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 del /q "%%i"
)
ENDLOCAL

Comment: sayyed, `echo %%i` would probably better read as, `echo %%~ni`, `find` should probably use the `/I` option and `Del` does not need a `/Q` option. Additionally, as you're inside a code block, the value of `%errorlevel%`, will not be reflected like that without delaying variable expansion, so I'd suggest changing it to `If ErrorLevel 1` instead.

Comment: I have tested and found the there was a missing % mark inline two. based on the question there was no requirement of validating case sensitivity.  yes, It is better to add variable expansion.

Comment: @sayyed, my comment was made after you fixed your `%` characters, and, it isn't 'better to add variable expansion', your code will not work properly unless you do, _(or use the alternative I offered, or use `echo %%~ni |find /i "Project"||del "%%i"`)_.

Comment: @compo:  I am not an expert in batch. New to the batch and new to this community.  I accept all your suggestions.  This code was using on my pc. Each suggestion is truly helpful to me. thank you so much.

Comment: @sayyed, if you're not an expert, you've been told that your code doesn't work as intended, and you've been provided with alternatives/fixes, you should perform an action based upon that advice. If you do not fix your answer, it will remain wrong, and if your answer is wrong there's nothing to stop any visitor from downvoting it as `This answer is not useful`. Please, either correct your code, or delete it, if you do not wish to receive future downvotes.